# Angularjs: cannot get bootstrap data-toggle working if dynamically appended to page

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

this is my first post, so be patient!
I managed (hope) to attach a working code snippet as simple as possible.

As I told in the subject I canoot get data-toggle bootstrap checkboxes be rendered if added to page via angular. Running the snippet you can see a static checkbox (bootstrap rendered) and a button to add more checkboxes 
(not rendered)

Any hep appreciated
BTW I'm really new to angular too

```js
var bootstrapTest = angular.module('boostrapTest', []);

bootstrapTest.service('loadDataService', function() {
    return {
             LoadToggle: function() {
                return '<label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle"></label>'
             }
    }
});
/**
 * Controllers
 */

bootstrapTest.controller('bootstrapTestController', function($scope, $compile, loadDataService) {

    $scope.doLoadToggle = function (){
        var myToggle = loadDataService.LoadToggle ();
        var outputMainScope = angular.element(document.getElementById('output_main'));
        // var temp = $compile(myToggle)($scope);
        outputMainScope.append(myToggle)
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>dynamyc apply bootstrap testing</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="testBootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- (load bootstrap) CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- (load bootstrap) js -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- (end load bootstrap) -->
</head>
<body ng-app="boostrapTest">
<div id="body" ng-controller="bootstrapTestController">
  <div id="header">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle"> static
        </label>
        <input type="button" ng-click="doLoadToggle()" value="CaricaToggle" >
  </div>
  <div id="output_main">
        <p >pippo</p>
    </div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is very far from how you're supposed to use Angular. You can't just insert raw HTML into the DOM and expect it to work. It's also completely unnecessary to attempt something like that to get a simple toggle into the DOM. If you want the toggle to only be visible if your checkbox is checked, then use an `ngIf` or `ngShow`/`ngHide` based approach.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver. I understand, and I'm new to angular, but this is only an example. In the real business I need to add many checkboxes (bootstrap styled as data-toggle) as resulting from a server side python query.

Comment: That doesn't change anything regarding what I said. It's still the wrong approach.

Comment: The question is why data-toggle does not work in this scenario and a bare checkbox is displayed? Can I get it working someway?

Comment: Any hint on which would be a different and better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I will deviate a bit from my answer to clarify some basic aspects.

The Angular concept for manipulating the DOM is the directive. You can begin by reading a tutorial about Angular directives, there are plenty available via a simple Google search. Take for example [this one](https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/). You should not modify the DOM from outside of a directive, as this is not a good practice and can lead to undesired effects (Google is full of examples as of why).

Back to your specific case: you don't need to even use directives. You can simply make use of a controller and a view. Once you understand what needs to be done, then you can refactor your code as follows:

- The controller should maintain an array of the current checkboxes. Let's simply call it `$scope.checkboxes`. Each element can be a JavaScript object with 2 properties `{ title: string, checked: boolean };
- Your view should use an ng-repeat directive to insert a list of checkboxes based on the data in the `$scope.checkboxes`. ng-repeat, as a directive, will ensure that it manipulates the DOM and injects the proper HTML elements without you having to explicitly do so).
- Your controller exposes a function for adding a new checkbox to `$scope.checkboxes`. This will be called when you click the *Carica Toggle* button. Once a new element is added into the checkboxes array, Angular's databinding and the ng-repeat directive will ensure that your view gets properly updated.

Here is an untested snippet of your controller:

```
bootstrapTest.controller('bootstrapTestController', function($scope, ...) {
  $scope.checkboxes = [];

  $scope.doLoadToggle = function() {
    $scope.checkboxes.push({
      title: "Checkbox " + $scope.checkboxes.length,
      checked: false
    })
  }
}
```

and the associated view

```
<body ng-app="boostrapTest">
  <div id="body" ng-controller="bootstrapTestController">
    <div ng-repeat="cb in checkboxes">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb.checked"> {{ cb.title }}
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="doLoadToggle()" value="Carica Toggle" >
  </div>
```

Hope that helps, this can be further refactored by adding a service which manages the checkboxes and their state and by introducing a custom directive for a list of checkboxes if the project complexity requires you to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your time here! Your answer make me clearly understand using ng-repeat and ng-for is a cleaner alternative to appending lots of html to the DOM...

Comment: @Roberto, don't forget to upvote answers and/or mark them as "correct".